# Bash/Tcl: How to rename randomly generated names located in the same column in text file?

Tags: bash, tcl

The following problem is looking weird for me.

Consider the following log file:

```
--------------------------------------------------
-----                INPUT DATA              -----
--------------------------------------------------
           NAME                    Atribute1   Atribute2
--------------------------------------------------
name                               0           0
name1                              8           7 
name5                              3           3   
name3                              4           2
name22                             5           8

...
//Skipped ....                            ...     

---------------------------------------------------
-----                INPUT DATA               -----
---------------------------------------------------
           NAME                    Attribute1   Attribute2 
---------------------------------------------------
name10                             0            0
name1                              8            7
name3                              0            0
name22                             0            0
name33                             9            0
name45                             0            0
...                                                  ...
//Skipped ....
```

The names from first column are generated and actually *I know nothing about them*.

**Question:**
How to rename all the names from first column to get something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------
-----                INPUT DATA              -----
--------------------------------------------------
           NAME                    Atribute1   Atribute2
--------------------------------------------------
x                                      0        0
x1                                     8        7 
x2                                     3        3   
x3                                     4        2
x4                                     5        8

---------------------------------------------------
-----                INPUT DATA                       -----
---------------------------------------------------
           NAME                    Attribute1   Attribute2 
---------------------------------------------------
x5                                  0           0
x1                                  8           7
x3                                  0           0
x6                                  0           0
x7                                  9           0
x8                                  0           0
x9                                  0           0
x10                                 0           0
```

That is to rename initial names with x-es: "x1, x2...."

**Restriction:** Same `x(i)` should be assigned to duplicate names.
As in the example: name1 and name3 also exist in 2nd table, thus their new names are the same in both of the tables (x1, x3).

I'm looking for solution in bash or tcl (bash is more preferred)

Comment: Do you mean pure bash (i.e. using the read builtin and doing string processing inside bash), or using just bash and core utilities? ... Also I wrote my answer assuming that the your input is already split up into two files. Do you have one giant log file with a header that is sometimes repeated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is use `awk` inside a shell script to keep track of the the mapping between the original names and the newly generated names. This particular awk script treats the first file differently by comparing `NR` and `FNR` built-in variables that count the total number of records processed and the number of records processed in the current file, respectively. More information about this trick here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106645/processing-two-files-using-awk

Basically, this program keeps track of a counter `c` and a dictionary `name` that maps the original name to the new one (which is just `c` with a prefix of `"x"`).

There are also two kinds of lines. Header lines begin with `"-"` or `" "`, those are ignored and printed as-is.

One thing you might need to do is split up the file afterwards, unless the files are supposed to be concatenated.

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '
    BEGIN { c = 0; }

    /^[- ]/ {
        print;
    }

    /^[^- ]/ && NR == FNR {
        new_name = "x" c;
        name[$1] = new_name;
        c += 1;
        $1 = new_name;
        print;
    }

    /^[^- ]/ && NR != FNR {
        if ($1 in name)  {
            $1 = name[$1];
        } else {
            new_name = "x" c;
            c += 1;
            $1 = new_name;
        }
        print;
    }

' input.txt input2.txt
```

Note that this program does no formatting, `awk` has a `printf` function that can be used to format data with a fixed number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Tcl: Use a dictionary. If the name already exists. If not, add it to the dictionary. Either way, give out the replacement name.

```
set names {}
proc lookup name {
    global names
    if {![dict exists $names $name]} {
        dict set names $name [dict size $names]
    }
    return x[dict get $names $name]
}
```

If globals bother you, you can hide them in a namespace:

```
namespace eval names {
namespace export lookup
    variable names
    set names {}
    proc lookup name {
        variable names
        if {![dict exists $names $name]} {
            dict set names $name [dict size $names]
        }
        return x[dict get $names $name]
    }
}
```

Documentation:
[! (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm),
[global](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[variable](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/variable.htm)